# Labels of plot images in R

Tags: r, pie-chart, label

I'm using **R** to retrieve data from a DB and to generate some nice plots. In particular, I can see that when I generate a *pie plot* as follows:

```
library(plotrix)
library(RODBC)
channel<-odbcConnect("MySql")
sqlQuery(channel,"use mydb")
res <-sqlQuery(channel, "SELECT categorystats.name categorystats.totalclick FROM categorystats")

png(filename="pie.png", width=800, height=800)

slices <- res$totalclick
lbls <- res$name
pct <- round(slices/sum(slices)*100)    
lbls <- paste(lbls, pct) # add percents to labels
lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="") # add % to labels
pie3D(slices,labels = lbls,explode=0.1,main="Categorie di prodotti più visitate") 

dev.off()
odbcClose(channel)
```

I obtain the following pie plot: [image: plot]

Unfortunately, some labels are not shown inside the image.

**Exists such a command to use to make the pie plot and the related labels fitting the image size?**

Comment: try adjusting the labelcex parameter for the size of the label font, then mar() to adjust the margins around the plot e.g. mar(3,3,3,3)

Comment: You know that every time you plot one of these another puppy dies?

Comment: @mdsumner What? Are you drunken?

Comment: @mdsumner Yeah, of course it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a reproducible example, I can't provide a definitive answer, but here are a few things to try:

1) Shrink the size of the pie to leave more room for the labels. You can do this by adding, say, `radius=0.8` (or whatever value works for you) in the call to `pie3D`. That will probably be sufficient to solve your problem.

2) Play with the margins to see if you can create more room for the labels. You can do this by adding `mar=c(bottom, left, top, right)` to the `pie3D` call. Each value is the size of the margin given as a number of lines.

3) Your labels are already a bit small, but you can make them smaller by adding `labelcex=0.9` (or whatever scaling factor works for you) to the `pie3D` call.

4) You can also play with the label position using `labelpos` in the `pie3D` call. Play around with the example in the help for `pie3D` to see how this works.

I'm going to finish with some unsolicited advice ("Advice is the elevator music of life" my college president told us at our graduation, and then proceeded to give us a bunch of advice): Pie charts are a poor way to display data, because it's difficult to discern differences in the area of different slices. A perspective pie chart only makes it worse by distorting the relative areas of the different slices. Adding 3D to a 2D object makes it even more difficult to compare areas of slices. If you must use a pie chart, consider switching to a face-on (circular), 2D pie chart.

Comment: I tried all the four points. The one that worked for me is `radius=0.7`. Notice that it worked only when I switched to the `pie` function (i.e. the 2d standard version of the chart). Thank for your time. R.